# Where am I? - A Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> First, a preposition for where I go
>   Next is a liquid that's not quick to flow
>   Finally a word used to give permission
>   All of this defines my current position

Where am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're

> 'in' the toilet (place, stall) or 'on' a toilet (commode).

First, a preposition for where I go

> to

Next is a liquid that's not quick to flow

> oil

Finally a word used to give permission

> let

Comment: (Naq lbh jbhyq or va gur onguebbz) :D +1

Comment: Correct!  Also, technically you would be "on" this location, not "in" it.  Well, unless something very unfortunate happened to you.

Comment: I was thinking of Rot13(n choyvp gbvyrg) or (n gbvyrg fgnyy) but yeah that would have fit better!

Comment: Hm, I guess that rot13(bvy) might be quick to flow, for example rot13(byvir bvy).